# I can't find the database I created through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I created a database in python using the following commands:

```
import sqlite3
student_database = sqlite3.connect("student_database.db")
STD_DB_cursor = student_database.cursor()
STD_DB_cursor.execute("create table if not exists Student_1(name text, age integer, score integer)")
```

But when I navigate to the directory at which the python file exists (**which is in my D:\ drive**), I can't find the database file. I tried my best to find it on the C:\ drive or anywhere but I can't find it (with Dora's sound).

**What should I do???**

Comment: By default, it should be created in the same directory from which you run the program. Have you checked there specifically?

Comment: to find your current working directory, you can do `import os`, and then `os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little search, I found that it's saved at my C:\User\user_name\

Anyway, thanks to whoever tried to help